# Verify app purchase via Google Login

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, verification, android-pay

I've found plenty of documentation on how to verify in-app purchases.  But I want to verify the app being purchased, not anything in-app.  APKs are extremely easy to pirate.  What I want is before allowing a player to use multiplayer, to make them log into Google and verify from Google that they purchased the APK on Google Play.  (I'm not marketing on Amazon yet, I'll worry about that later).

I'm using Unity3d.  I'm able to get the Google Unity package to work just fine.  I'm able to integrate Achievements and Leaderboards just fine.  I'm just trying to figure out if there's a "yes they purchased this game" verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there's a licensing API.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

I think that meets your requirements?